# Remastersys refuses to dist in Ubuntu 14.04 due to: genisoimage: Volume ID string too long

Tags: 14.04, remastersys

When using both plain remastersys and remastersys-gtk in Ubuntu 14.04 give me a **genisoimage: Volume ID string too long** error when I look in the logs when I use the dist option. Apparently on the [mate-desktop forums](http://forums.mate-desktop.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=3160#p9944) a user found a fix for this, and as it seems it looks to be a 64bit only issue. I cannot figure out how to apply this fix to remastersys-gtk. I use the precise version [here](http://www.remastersys.com/) as the [14.04 version by mutse](https://launchpad.net/~mutse-young/+archive/ubuntu/remastersys) doesn't have a working gtk version. Can anyone help me apply this fix? As it seems to be an issue with 64bit users using 14.04 onwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I figured it out, I was having a brain fart when I posted this so I'm not that stupid if you think I am. The issue was that the CD Label name was too long for remastersys' liking, and I doubt it's a 64bit issue only. Easily fixable just condense the CD Label.

PS AskUbuntu won't let me claim this as an answer but this is the correct answer. This question should be closed now not in 2 days imo.